# github api to compare commits, response status is diverged

Tags: jenkins, conflict, github-api

When configuring jenkins, I want to detect feature branches whether they have merging conflicts, so I use github api v3 to test on 2 **intentional** conflicted branches.

After merge branch1 to master, I compared branch2(b2) like this:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/hao1987/myself/compare/hao1987:master...hao1987:b2
```

and it returns a long json which has an attribute:

`"status": "diverged"`

I wonder if that means conflict, and where I can try types of "status"

Answer (score 5):

This isn't documented (sorry!), but `status` can be one of four things:

- `"diverged"` = commits were introduced on both the head and base branch since the common ancestor
- `"ahead"` = commits were introduced on head after the common ancestor with base
- `"behind"` = commits were introduced on base after the common ancestor with head
- `"identical"` = branches point to same commit

So, `"diverged"` doesn't tell you whether a merge between the branches would result in merge conflicts.